# Spyder affects internet quality

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I am new to SO, so please bear with me. I am currently diving into spyder IDE to model and manipulate some machine learning algorithms. However, as soon as I open spyder without opening any files yet, my internet becomes very slow and sometimes it disconnects from my laptop. I have tried wireless and wired connection, but the problem persists. When I close spyder, my internet immediately goes back to being fast again.I am currently using python 3.6, Anaconda 4.4.0, and spyder 3.20 on windows 10. My question is :

### 1.Can spyder actually affect internet performance?

### 2.If it does what is the solution or alternative?

Thanks in advance, and if there is anything you would like to ask I would be more than happy to answer.

Comment: I have spyder open all the time and it doesn't affect my internet performance. You could try a different editor

Comment: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3601

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 I am not sure if I can see an answer in the link you have provided.